# Use a HashSet or List for a collection of Entities?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a class, which looks like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

    public FirstName FirstName { get; set; }
    public LastName LastName { get; set; }
    public Province Province { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders 
    {
        get { foreach (var order in _orders) yield return order; }
    }

    internal void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        _orders.Add(order);
    }
    //Planning to add an AddRange method to add a collection of Orders.
}
```

Someone suggested to me recently that I should be using a Set instead of a list as I do not need the index benefits of a list as it is exposed as an IEnumberable.

If I change this to a set, then how do I implement equality? I believe I have a few options:

1) Leave it as a list.

2) Do nothing - then I believe orders are unique based on referential equality.  Is there any risk doing this? Everywhere I read tells me that you must override Hashcode and equals if you are using a Hashset.  Here is an example of a Set, where the default Object.hashcode and object.equals appears to be used with a HashSet: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.DomainModel/Northwind/Entities/Order.cs

3) Override .equals and .hashcode in the Order class so that Orders are equal if they have the same ID.  This link suggests that you should not do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRCOKKUSp9s

4) Create an Entity base class similar to this: https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples_NET/blob/master/iddd_common/Domain.Model/Entity.cs.  The youtube video in point three appears to advise against this.

5) Implement an IEqualityComparer.  The research I have done suggests this is a bad idea because: 1) I will have to inject/pass a comparer into the entity and 2) The code for establising whether two orders are equal is in a different class to Order making the domain model anemic.

I am trying to follow the principle of least astonishment and find myself going round in circles sometimes trying to achieve this.  A lot of the links above are several years old.  Is there a standard way to approach this?

Comment: `Someone suggested to me recently that I should be using a Set instead of a list as I do not need the index benefits` and? Did that someone also say why is that so terrible? KISS!!! If using Set is causing you too much overhead, go with Lists. Do refactor later if you deem it necessary

Comment: @Laiv, thanks +1 for KISS.  That is what I thought.  They just said that I do not need the index benefits of a list and also a set is more efficient.

Comment: Does set guarantee order of items?  Because it sounds like the order of your Orders could be important.

Comment: @MetaFight, no I don't think so.  I don't need order.  I don't really understand your point.

Comment: And, as always, don't fall in the trap of pre-optimising.  Your time is more expensive than CPU cycles.

Comment: @w0051977, sorry, I was just trying to draw attention to the fact that, by switching to a Set, you'd be sacrificing other List features that you might actually need (eg, item order).

Comment: @Metafight, is it normal for a Hashset to establish equality using references like this: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.DomainModel/Northwind/Entities/Order.cs.  Notice that OrderLines are added to a Hashset and OrderLine does not override .equals/.hashcode/implement IEquality.

Comment: Take a look to this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/718a76de-90c7-4d09-b8aa-4dcd8333e729/when-to-use-hashset-class-instead-of-list?forum=csharpgeneral). Note that the author is pointing to some performance issues that could be mitigated by HashSets. However, you should not be worried about them till they become a real concern. Solve this sort of problems as they apear.

Comment: @Laiv, thanks that is very helpful.  Is it normal to use a list just to prevent other developers from adding duplicates by accident?

Comment: Duplicates are often checked as a business concern. Usually, there's an explicit control of such constraint.

Comment: @Laiv, "business concern" - do you mean it is down to the repository? Perhaps you could post an answer so that I can give some credit.

Comment: I'm thinking how could I give one, not falling in a opinionated answer. *What should I do* questions are dangerous. Is very easy to end up answering "what I would do" rather than "what the OP needs to do". Hard to say what you need with so little context of the project and it's circumstances.

Comment: @Laiv, could you explain what you mean by "business concern" in a comment then.  That should do it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Without understanding the larger design, it's impossible to know whether this class should be part of preventing duplicate orders.  In this scenario, I would typically use a Dictionary/Map (as opposed to a set) because it makes things a lot easier.  Usually there would be some sort of order id.  That's the key and then you can easily look things up and tell if you've received a duplicate request.  Sometimes a request can go through but a client never receives confirmation.  An easy way to deal with this is allow them to send the same request and ignore duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to approach the answer from different angles.

#### Premature optimization

You have been told that there're other collections whom, apparently, are more suitable your case. It's probably true, but I don't find the given arguments to be enough to make me believe that `List` is utterly out of place.

Ask yourself whether `HashSet` solves a real and known issue of the current implementation. Ask as well if these unused `List`'s capabilities are counterproductive. Finally, evaluate whether the effort of changing the implementation makes a big improvement. But don't spend too much time.

Wasting too much time answering these questions (or refactoring prematurely) instead of solving the problem, diminish the benefits of one or another implementation. Solving problems you don't have is premature optimization.

As @MetaFight says, your time is more valuable than CPU cycles.

#### Equality

What *Equality* means should be up to you to decide. The ubiquitous language has much to say here. If not, ask the domain experts when two `Orders` are *equals* and when they are exactly the *same*.

Checking these conditions should not depend on the collection type you choose. One type can help you out to achieve it easier than other, but not at the cost of condition the design.

Take the following in mind. *Equals* and *Same* are different things.

Two references could be:

- pointing to the **same** instance (in memory)
- pointing to different instances whose data are **equals**. What causes both to have the same hashcode.
- pointing to different instances, with different data and still have the same hashcode (collision). Rare, but possible.
- pointing to different instances, with different data and they to be considered equals by the domain, but not by the collection.

Delegating the control of *Equality* and *Same* to the collection might not be enough for you to express the business rules.

For example, if having *the same* `Order` twice in the same collection is not allowed but having *two equals* is, would be good to make this  constraint explicit with your own classes and functions<sup>3</sup>, so that other developers can "read" what *equal/same* mean and when these characteristics are important.

The reason for all of this is simple. Expressiveness.<sup>2</sup>

Implementing code to express the differences between "same" and "equals" <sup>1</sup> follows the principle of least astonishment since it's not required for us to be familiar with the SDK.

*Don't make us look in the SDK for us to know what are you trying to do.*

#### Testing

Short story long. If we delegate the responsibility to the collection, when it comes to testing, we would be testing the collection instead of the business rules.

#### KISS

One collection could be more suitable than others. But, if `List` meet the needs and it's the simplest solution, then go with `List`. What collection to use is *technical detail*. Ideally, the domain model is agnostic to this sort of details. If it's, it's easier for you to change the implementation from one collection to another.

---

<sup>1: Or any other constraint of the domain</sup>

<sup>2: I suggest you to read @VoiceOfUnreason's answer for more insights regarding this subject</sup>

<sup>3: or other elements of the domain</sup>

Comment: +1 for KISS principle.  Say I was to introduce a hashset in the future.  Is it ever acceptable not to rely on default  equality? Everywhere I read says you MUST not do this.  However, if you are happy to rely on default equality then I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: If It meet the needs, then it's ok. What matters to me is to be aware of the consequences of the choices we do. So, if we ever are proved to be wrong, we know why and how to address it.

Comment: If it meet the needs, then it's ok. What matters to me is to be aware of the consequences of the choices we do. So, if we ever are proved to be wrong, we know why and how to address it. Again, the principle of the least astonishment.

Comment: Finally, what dot you mean by "make this constraint explicit with code".  Are you saying that the repository should return the distinct orders?

Comment: I do mean to implement the control of Equality, duplicated orders, etc, with your own code (classes, functions, etc). Where to put that code depends on the case. Some may go in repositories, others in aggregates. Who do you think is responsible of each decision?

Comment: I guess it could go in the repository or in the aggregate.  If in aggregate then could do: IsSameOrder() like VoiceOfUnreason said.  I have asked VoiceOfUnreason to clarify why what he/she has written applies to value objects.

Comment: Your link above (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/718a76de-90c7-4d09-b8aa-4dcd8333e729/when-to-use-hashset-class-instead-of-list?forum=csharpgeneral) references this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections.  It states: "DO use ReadOnlyCollection<T>, a subclass of ReadOnlyCollection<T>, or in rare cases IEnumerable<T> for properties or return values representing read-only collections.".  Do you think I am right to design my class like this with a list that is exposed as an IEnumerable?

Comment: This should be the last thing I want to clarify before accepting.

Comment: Hard to say without more context. Is inmutability what you want? Is inmutability what you got?

Comment: I don't want clients to be able to modify the collection except through AddOrder and AddOrder range.  Add order range will only add active orders to Customer.Orders I.e. it will filter the collection that is passed to it.

Comment: Leave It as it's. Later, if you find your self needing features from IReadOnlyCollection, change It.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me as though you are getting tangled because you are mixing two different abstraction layers here.

List and HashMap are *data structures*, they are different ways of arranging collections in memory (with slightly different invariants).  Your domain models normally shouldn't care about this level of detail.

Compare with

```
private readonly OrderHistory _orders = new OrderHistory();
```

The model for customer doesn't need to know the details of how orders are represented in memory, it just needs to know the semantics of accessing them.

Your value types are typically where you start worrying about specific in memory representations.  A good exercise to help emphasize this is the [probability kata](https://gist.github.com/gregoryyoung/1018570/69fa7a9191161d7107a20c6d7322e2cd52520291).  They bridge the gap between the semantics of the model and *some* data structure that supports those semantics.

In other words, the OrderHistory abstraction should be insulating the model from the decision you have made about which in memory representation to use.
See Parnas on [decomposing systems into modules](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/).

Now, for *equality*, you need to understand the *semantics* in your model.

That is, if `lhs === rhs`, what guarantees are implied?  What two things being equal really tells you is that, for some family of functions `f`, `f(lhs) == f(rhs)`.  But the family of functions there depends on your domain model.

For instance - do two different histories have to enumerate their entries in the same order?  Do they have to point to the same objects (same locations in memory), or just objects that are equivalent? (If orders are "value objects", then you probably only need them to be equivalent.)

The semantic constraints on "equality" in your model might be *more permissive* than those provided by your collection library.

Because the details are encapsulated, you have an opportunity to perform any necessary conversions.  For instance suppose you already have some function `isSameHistory(IList<Order> lhs, IList<Order> rhs)` and you've testing for equality like

```
boolean isSameCustomer(Customer lhs, Customer rhs) {
    return isSameHistory(lhs._orders, rhs._orders);
}
```

and you later need to re-implement `_orders` as an array?  There's a pretty quick refactoring available

```
boolean isSameCustomer(Customer lhs, Customer rhs) {
    return isSameHistory(lhs._orders.toList(), rhs._orders.toList());
}
```

Meaning that switching from one representation to another in a *functionally* equivalent way should be straight forward.  You might have to do some refactoring work in advance to [make this change *easy*](https://www.prod.facebook.com/notes/kent-beck/mastering-programming/1184427814923414).

Comment: Great answer. I would dare to say also that if we model the constraints explicitly rather than laying on the technical details of the data structure, only take us to implement the unit test of these constraints for us to change implementations with guarantee. Otherwise, we would be just testing the proper functioning of the data structure (unecessary) and bound to whatever the future holds for it.

Comment: Thanks for referencing the Parnas paper, which, IMO, is far better and far clearer than the overrated SRP.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: "If orders are "value objects", then you probably only need them to be the same.".  When you say "the same" I assume you mean referential equality.  Why is this specific to value objects? +1.

Comment: That part of the answer wasn't expressed well, rephrased.